# Determine if two grammars for the same language are ambiguous

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, ambiguity

I'm reading the book: *Formal Syntax and Semantics of Programming Languages*. I don't understand this exercise:

> Consider the following two grammars, each of which generates strings of correctly balanced parentheses and brackets. Determine if either or both is ambiguous. The Greek letter ε represents an empty string.
>
> ```
> <string> ::= <string> <string> | ( <string> ) | [ <string> ] | ε
> <string> ::= ( <string> ) <string> | [ <string> ] <string> | ε
> ```

Comment: Note that it's the *grammar* that may or may not be ambiguous, not the language. Do you understand the definition of an ambiguous grammar?

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? Do you understand the definition of ambiguity? Have you had a look at other questions tagged [tag:ambiguity]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this a hint.  As I write in my comment, what is the syntax tree of `()()()`?  Does the first two pairs belong to the leftmost of the `<string><string>`-part, or does the two latter pairs belong to the rightmost?

$$ \left(
 \overbrace{  \overbrace{ () }^\text{string} \quad
 \overbrace{ () }^\text{string}}^\text{string}
\quad \overbrace{ () }^\text{string} \right)
\text{ vs }
\left(
 \overbrace{ () }^\text{string}\quad
 \overbrace{  \overbrace{ () }^\text{string}\quad
 \overbrace{ () }^\text{string}}^\text{string} \right)
$$